# How can I only display non-zero integers?

Tags: java

Using `System.out.println()`, how can I only display integers that are not zero? For example, if I have variables `a = 4`, `b = 5`, and `c = 3`, they should all print. Now if we subtract 3 from `c`, it becomes `a = 4`, `b = 5`, and `c = 0`. How do I only display `a` and `b`, but not `c`?

Comment: `if ( a > 0 ) System.out.println(a);`. Or make a list of the variables you want to output, then loop through the list an only print members of the list that are greater than zero.

Comment: nope, I meant how can I display A and B only, since the value of c is zero...

Comment: this is for a game, and I need only both a and b to appear:

Comment: The actual problem here isn't directly related to game development, so this question should probably be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (a != 0)
  System.out.println(a);
if (b != 0)
  System.out.println(b);
if (c != 0)
  System.out.println(c);
```

You probably want them in an array though, to make it easier and more organized.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: this replaces zero values with the string `-`.  Of course, you can use any other value instead, including an empty string if you want.

```
System.out.println( a == 0 ? "-" : a );
System.out.println( b == 0 ? "-" : b );
System.out.println( c == 0 ? "-" : c );
```

This uses the [ternary conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) `CONDITION ? VALUE_IF_TRUE : VALUE_IF_FALSE`.  This operator has rather low [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), so if you want to use it as part of a longer expression, you should usually enclose it in parentheses, like this:

```
System.out.println( "A = " + ( a == 0 ? "-" : a ) );
System.out.println( "B = " + ( b == 0 ? "-" : b ) );
System.out.println( "C = " + ( c == 0 ? "-" : c ) );
```

Or course, you can also use ordinary `if` statements to get the same effect, it's just more verbose (but also more flexible):

```
if ( a == 0 )
    System.out.println( "A is zero" );
else
    System.out.println( "A = " + a );
```